# Values not getting modified inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I am coming from a C++, python background and recently started learning C#. But I stumbled upon a peculiar problem, which I can't figure out after spending considerable time on it. Please forgive if it seems too basic as I am trying out some algorithmic coding questions to learn the language.

I have this code

```
public class Solution {
    public int SmallestRangeII(int[] A, int K) {
        float mean = A.Sum() / A.Length;
        Console.WriteLine($"the mean is {mean}");

        int mini = int.MinValue;
        int maxi = int.MaxValue;
        foreach(int x in A) {
            int temp = x + ((x - mean) < 0 ? K : -K);
            Console.WriteLine($"{temp}");
            mini = Math.Min(mini, temp);
            maxi = Math.Max(maxi, temp);
            Console.WriteLine($"{mini} and {maxi}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"the maximum and minimum values are {maxi} and {mini}");
        return maxi - mini;
    }
}
```

When I pass, the arguments, `A = [1]` and `K = 0`, on executing this code, I get the output :

```
the mean is 1
1
-2147483648 and 2147483647
the maximum and minimum values are 2147483647 and -2147483648
```

In the first iteration of the loop, why aren't the `maxi` and `mini` getting modified to 1 and 1 respectively?

Comment: Because - `Math.Min(int.MinValue, 1);` - `int.MinValue` is smaller and `Math.Max(int.MaxValue, 1);` - `int.MaxValue` is bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, so i can not provide a solution, but if you look at your code you can see, that min = -2^31 and your temp variable equals one in the case you provided. Math.Min of those two numbers obviously picks the smaller number -> -2^31. The same with the maximum.

If you try to get the biggest and smallest nimber in the array try changing the first assignment of your min and max to

```
int min = int.MaxValue();
int max = int.MinValue();
```

This will lead to your desired solution i guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

- Foreach loop will iterate only once as your array contain single element
- Value of temp is calculated as 1.

  `int temp = x + ((x - mean) < 0 ? K : -K);`

*because value of `K` is `0` and adding x i.e. 1 to it as per your input.*

If you want to get min and max value based on 0 then it will provide same result as you received in input

Best way to understand what value is storing in variable, you can use `Console.WriteLine()`. Which will print result on console for you. Something like

```
   foreach(int x in A) {
        int temp = x + ((x - mean) < 0 ? K : -K);
        Console.WriteLine($"x: "+{x}+"\t mean: "+{mean}+"\t K: "+{K});
        Console.WriteLine($"mini: "+{mini}+"\t maxi: "+{maxi});
        Console.WriteLine($"{temp}");
        mini = Math.Min(mini, temp);
        maxi = Math.Max(maxi, temp);
        Console.WriteLine($"{mini} and {maxi}");
    }
```

***Or Debug your code***

Comment: opps, I overlooked ` **x+** <rest of calculation`. Updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since `mini` is initialized to `int.MinValue`, `Math.Min(mini, temp)` will always be `int.MinValue`

You probably wanted to initialize the other way round: `mini` with `int.MaxValue` and `maxi` with `int.MinValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You set the **int.MinValue** to **mini** and **int.MaxValue** to **maxi** before **foreach** method and then you called the Min and Max method to fetch minimum and maximum values. You should consider that at the first iteration, the value of the mini is -2147483648, so you call Min method like this :

```
mini = Math.Min(-2147483648, 1);
```

This method works properly for you. If you want to set the **mini** value to 1, then you have multiple choices. One of them is changing the mini and maxi type to nullable integer(int?).

```
int? mini;
int? maxi;
```

And then check its value inside the **foreach** like following:

```
foreach (int x in A)
{
    int temp = x + ((x - mean) < 0 ? K : -K);
    Console.WriteLine($"{temp}");
    if(mini.HasValue)
        mini = Math.Min(mini.Value, temp);
    else
        mini = temp;

    if(maxi.HasValue)
        maxi = Math.Max(maxi.Value, temp);
    else
        maxi = temp;
    Console.WriteLine($"{mini} and {maxi}");
}
```